# Cocoa Paste to NSTextView in code

Tags: cocoa, paste, nstextview

Thanks for the help.

I just need to paste the contents of the clipboard/pasteboard to an NSTextView by way of an action.

```
NSString *PboardType = @"PboardType";

- (IBAction)paste:sender

 {
NSPasteboard *pb = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
NSData *copiedData = [pb dataForType:PboardType];
[self RTFFromRange:copiedData];
}
```

The last line is obviously wrong. what do I need to do?

Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing. An NSTextView already supports pasting (and cutting and copying, and fonts, and search, and spelling-checking, and …). You don't need to do anything to implement it.

If you're implementing some different paste behavior, you should edit your question to specify what special behavior you're trying to achieve (as well as why the user will want your application to do something unusual).

If the standard paste behavior isn't working, you should edit your question to specify *how* it isn't working.

Comment: Hey Peter, I don't owe you an explanation, nor do you owe me an answer or any help for that matter. Have a little patience with people who are trying to learn something new instead of coming across as a sour puss. Think about it - maybe I want to include additional functions in Paste action?

Comment: @Paul: I covered that possibility in my answer. I would appreciate it if you'd tell me specifically how I'm being impatient or “a sour puss”.

Comment: @Paul @Peter I agree with Peter that more information is needed in order to give you a more detailed answer, and one that suits your needs (which aren’t really clear). For all we know, invoking `[super paste:sender]` could be enough for ‘maybe I want to include additional functions in Paste action.’

Comment: Peter, you're correct. I was out of line. I apologize. When I have time I'll elaborate on what I was trying to do ...